# Finding out who got the highest mark among the students

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie in python and currently working a project to sort and calculate the marks among the students. I was asked to find out who got the highest mark among the students.

if only one student, it will output: [name] gets the highest mark.
if only two student, it will output: [name] and [name] get the highest mark.
if more than two students, it will output:[name], [name] and [name] get the highest marks.

However, I was stuck at more than two student students and dunno how to meet the above requirement, for example if there is a class with 40students and all of them got the same marks, my program does not work. I thought of recursion but I dunno its a good direction or not.

Here is what I got now:

```
marks = {'Sally': 65, 'Ken': 61, 'Michael': 88, 'Yan': 67, 'Mary': 88,'May': 88}
highest = max(marks.values())
n = [k for k, v in marks.items() if v == highest]

if len(n)==1:
    print(n[0],' got the highest mark')
elif len(n)==2:
    print(n[0],'and',n[1],' got the highest mark')
elif len(n)==3:
    print(n[0],',',n[1],'and',n[2],' got the highest mark')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to break the problem down into logical steps. What should the result look like for a length of 4, 5, etc.? Do you see a **pattern**? Aside from `1` and `2`, are there actually any special cases? What text needs to be put in between the last two values? What text needs to be put in between each other adjacent pair of values? So - we need to *repeat* the process of putting *the same* text in between *all the pairs except the last* - right? So - what is your question about this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it using `''.join(<listhere>)`.
Here's the code:

```
marks = {'Sally': 65, 'Ken': 61, 'Michael': 88, 'Yan': 67, 'Mary': 88,'May': 88}
highest = max(marks.values())
n = [k for k, v in marks.items() if v == highest]
str1 = ', '.join(n)
print(str1, 'got the highest mark')
```

Comment: Seems you're missing the "name, name and name" part of the requirement.

Comment: it required me to separate the last and second last name with "and"

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the if block with a simple for loop like this

```
for i in range(len(n)):
if(i < len(n)-1): # for the name which is not the last of n
    print(n[i]+", ", end="")
else:
    print("and " + n[i] + " got the highest mark")
```

Comment: it required me to separate the last and second last name with "and"

Comment: I have edit the answer. You just put "and " before n[i] in else case

Answer (score 0):

```
mystr = ', '.join(n[:-1]) + ' and ' + n[-1] if len(n)>1 else n[0] 
print ( mystr + ' got the highest marks')
#Michael, Mary and May got the highest marks
```

Comment: While a very good solution, noe this produces in the case of a single highest mark: `# Mary got the higest marks` (plural)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and list indices.

```
marks = {'Sally': 65, 'Ken': 61, 'Michael': 88, 'Yan': 67, 'Mary': 88, 'May': 88}
highest = max(marks.values())
toppers_list = [name for name, score in marks.items() if score == highest]

for student in toppers_list[:-1]:
    print(student, end=', ')

print("and", toppers_list[-1], "scored highest marks.")
```

`toppers_list[:-1]` creates a list with the name of all the students that scored the highest, except for the last one.

`print(student, end=', ')` will prevent a newline after every print, and will separate all names with a comma (and a space).

---

**Output:**

```
Michael, Mary, and May scored highest marks.
```

Hope this helps.